# Jest + Coverage + VueJs how to cover vue methods?

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, code-coverage, vue-test-utils, ts-jest

I was trying to cover the codes to increase the coverage
report percentage,

**How to cover the if statement inside vue methods?**

In my case using `@vue/test-utils:"^1.1.4"` and `vue: "^2.6.12"` package version, FYI, And below is my actual component,

```
<template>   
    <div :class="iconcls" >
        <el-image 
            ref='cal-modal'
            class="icons" 
            @click="handleRedirectRouter(urlname)"
            :src="require(`@/assets/designsystem/home/${iconurl}`)" 
            fit="fill" />
        <div class="desc" >{{ icondesc }}</div>
    </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue, Prop } from 'vue-property-decorator';

@Component({
  components: {}
})
class IconHolder extends Vue {
    @Prop({ default: "" }) iconcls!: any;
    @Prop({ default: "" }) iconurl!: any;
    @Prop({ default: "" }) icondesc!: any;
    @Prop({ default: "" }) urlname!: any;

    handleRedirectRouter(url: string) {
        if (url !== "") {
            this.$router.push({ name: url });
        }
    }
}

export default IconHolder;
</script>
```

**Coverage Report for Iconholder.vue component**

[image: Coverage Report for Iconholder.vue component]

EDIT 2 : Ater @tony updation,

i have tried with this below test suties but still getting errors,

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";
import IconHolder from '@/components/designsystem/Home/IconHolder.vue';
import ElementUI, { Image } from "element-ui";
import { mount, createLocalVue } from '@vue/test-utils';
const localVue = createLocalVue();
localVue.use(Vuex);
localVue.use(ElementUI, {
    Image
});

Vue.component('el-image', Image);

describe("IconHolder.spec.vue", () => {

    it('pushes route by name', async () => {
        const push = jest.fn();      
        const wrapper = mount(IconHolder, {
          propsData: {
            iconcls:"dshomesec5_comp_icons",
            icondesc:"about",
            iconurl:"components_icn_15.svg",
            urlname: 'about'
          },
          mocks: {
            $router: {
              push
            }
          }
        })
        await wrapper.findComponent({ name: 'el-image' }).trigger('click');
        expect(push).toHaveBeenCalledWith({ name: 'about' });
    })    

})
```

**ERROR REPORT:**

```
expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...expected)

Expected: {"name": "about"}

Number of calls: 0

  30 |         })
  31 |         await wrapper.findComponent({ name: 'el-image' }).trigger('click');
> 32 |         expect(push).toHaveBeenCalledWith({ name: 'about' })
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a unit test that runs that method with a non-empty string for `url`.

1. Mount the component with an [initial non-empty `urlname` prop](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/options.html#propsdata).
2. [Mock the `$router.push` method](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/options.html#mocks) with [`jest.fn()`](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestfnimplementation), which we'll use to verify the call later.
3. [Find the `el-image` component](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/wrapper/#findcomponent) that is bound to that method (as a `click` handler).
4. [Trigger](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/wrapper/#trigger) the `click` event on that component.
5. [Verify `$router.push` was called](https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#tohavebeencalledwitharg1-arg2-) with the specified `urlname`.

```js
it('pushes route by name', () => {
  /* 2 */
  const push = jest.fn()

  const wrapper = shallowMount(IconHolder, {
    /* 1 */
    propsData: {
      urlname: 'about'
    },
    /* 2 */
    mocks: {
      $router: {
        push
      }
    }
  })

                 /* 3 */                            /* 4 */
  await wrapper.findComponent({ name: 'el-image' }).trigger('click')

  /* 5 */
  expect(push).toHaveBeenCalledWith({ name: 'about' })
})
```

Comment: Hey bro, I have updated my test suites above, Still im getting errors like above, Kindly help me to fix this issue.

Comment: "vue": "^2.6.12",  "@vue/test-utils": "^1.1.4",

Comment: Can you post a link to a project that reproduces the issue?

Comment: I'm looking for a project that reproduces the error you're seeing when you run the unit test. The project you linked just gives me the application code.

Comment: ERROR REPORT already abouve query itself i have updated.